# What Serializer and Deserializer to use for Kafka Producer/Consumer?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

In an Spring Boot Activity Stream POC, I am using Kafka. Currently, I have objects in the application that models Person, Create, Like, Follow, etc as specified in W3C ActivityStream 2.0. My question is:

What is the best serializer to use in the Producer to send the objects to a topic? Inbuilt ByteArraySerializer, StringSerializer, or create custom serializer?
More importantly Why?

Same applies to the consumer too.

Thanks in advance.